# Refresh html input element value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the value of a html input element and I want to see the value change on screen. This seems to be a very simple task but it is not working using javascript (but it work with jQuery).

```js
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#test1").val("10");
});

function bt() {
  document.getElementById("test1").value = "3333";
    document.getElementById("test1").setAttribute("value","4444");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Formula 1:
    <input type="text" id="test1" value="1111">
    </p>

    <p>What the answers to these formulas?</p>
    <br>
    <button id="btn1">Hint</button>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="bt()">Hint2</button>
```

Any suggestion with the javascript function bt() ?

Comment: Setting the `.value` does work for me with this example. Can you show a [mcve] of your code?

Comment: Here's an odd thing: I just converted your code example in to an executable snippet - and it works just fine.

Comment: buttons submit forms, is it in a form?

Comment: Code snippet works fine.

Comment: A value is not an attribute, it is a property.  Work to understand that when a property changes, the attribute may not change.

Comment: I am considering voting to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003819/125981 please provide clarification as to why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `value` property of the `input` element after being selected/referenced in `JavaScript`.

In the next example, every time you click on the `button` with `change value` text the `input` value will change to `New value:` followed by `a random number`.

```js
/** selecting the button and the input **/
const btn = document.getElementById('btn2'),
  inp = document.getElementById('test1');

/** adding click listener  **/
btn.addEventListener('click', () => inp.value = 'New value: ' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)); /** for demo purposes a random number is generated every time the button is clicked. Change the affected value per your requirements **/
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test1" value="1111">

<p>What the answers to these formulas?</p>
<br>
<button id="btn1">Hint</button>
<button id="btn2">change value</button>
```

> Learn more on [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) element in `JavaScript`.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: How does this improve upon the OPs example?

Comment: I'd argue that it's considerably more complicated - seeing as they just want to change the value to a fixed one on click. It's also unrelated to the OPs problem as their code works. Don't get me wrong, I haven't downvoted you - I just don't think this is relevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: just for the demo purposes I did use a generated number. The OP can build on my attempt with any "values" he would like to use. Also, I just meant to illuminate his way, so using `value` attribute of the `HTMLInputElement` is more robust than using `setAttribute` function By the way, having such conversations would, without any doubt, make SO better.